# Handle exception on IClientMessageInspector

Tags: wcf, exception, iclientmessageinspector

I have calling wcf service and I implemented IClientMessageInspector interface.

I want to handle error on AfterReceiveReply. The fault exception should always return 200 status code with custom message and error code. It should not throw any exception on service call.

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            if (reply.IsFault)
            {
                // wrap message with http status code 200 and return content as exception model like status code, exception message;
            }
        }
```

I want to handle exception and it always return response without any exception that I will handle in cusumer code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try HttpResponseMessageProperty, it contains the status code of the returned Message.

```
 if (reply.IsFault)
        {
            if (reply.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty pro = reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
                pro.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

            }
            else
            {
                reply.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, new HttpResponseMessageProperty { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK });
            }
        }
```

But the message has returned by server, if server throws exception, you may not be able to  receive the message in the AfterReceiveReply method.

If this doesn't work, I suggest you could do this using IDispatchMessageInspector at server side to change the status code before sending response. (If you have control over server side)
http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/02/10/make-use-of-wcf-faultcontracts-in-silverlight-clients/

Comment: I tried your sample code and its working. I am using third party WCF service and I don't have control over it. Is there any other way to handle an exception and I can raise my own custom exception.